# complicate regexp matching words (is it possible?)

Tags: regex, utf-8

I want a regex to match all Greek (utf-8) words that do NOT:

- end with `.`
- end with `-`
- end with `'`
- end with numbers (1-9)
- start with `.`
- start with `,`
- start with `-`
- the first letter is capital
- all letters are capital

Is this possible? To match Greek words I use `\p{Greek}{3,}` which matches Greek UTF-8 words that have at least 3 characters.

I write programs in ruby, but if it can be done in perl or any other cli tool/language I'll write a script to dump the output in a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<!\S)(?=\S*\p{Greek})(?![-,.\p{Lu}])(?![\p{Lu}\P{L}]+\b)\S+(?<![-.'1-9])(?!\S)
```

Let's break this beasty down:

- The core of the regex is the `\S+` in the middle which is surrounded by a bunch of positive and negative assertions.
- `(?<!\S)` - The word must not be preceded by a non-whitespace character. This makes sure we don't start our match in the middle of a word.
- `(?=\S*\p{Greek})` - There must be at least one Greek letter in there somewhere.
- `(?![-,.\p{Lu}])` - The word must not start with a dash, comma, dot, or uppercase letter `\p{Lu}`.
- `(?![\p{Lu}\P{L}]+\b)` - The word must not be all uppercase letters and symbols.
- `(?<![-.'1-9])` - The word must not end with a dash, dot, apostrophe, or digit 1 through 9.
- `(?!\S)` - The word must not be followed by a non-whitespace character. This makes sure we don't end our match in the middle of a word.

Comment: It's a starting but doesn't work for me: http://d.pr/i/zbCN However it could a starting point.

Comment: @atmosx What words are incorrectly (not) matching? Can you paste them here so I can test?

Comment: I have [this text](http://pastebin.ca/2293783). Using your regex on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Yv0ErfMjVk) I match the following unwanted words: 

`[ΕΤΥΜ` - it has an `[` & its capital, `<` not a word, `avantare` it's English not Greek, `(η)` has `(` and `)`,  and so on.

Comment: Fixed so it doesn't match `[ETYM` or `<`. Added a check for at least one Greek letter.

Comment: Not related to your code, but there seems to be a bug with Ruby's implementation of Latin script - capital English alphabet characters are not matched.

Comment: It's not working 100% but once I extract these words I can pass it to my usual regex string and strip nuances like "κέρδη:" το "κέρδη" easily! Thanks!!! @nhathdh I'll keep that in mind!